# Max length of header value in IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, http-headers

Tomcat sends response which contains "Content-disposition:attachment; filename*=utf-8''myverylooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooname.docx."
And in all browsers it works well. But in IE7 filename truncated to the last 42 characters.
What should I do to prevent this truncation?

Thanks!

Comment: Maximum limit for IE id 2083 characters. I don't Think this file name is long Enough to cause any problem.

Comment: but this happens to all files which loaded only throught IE7. IE8 or IE9 works well. And I even can't look to IE console because IE7 doesn't have console

Comment: Thats Microsoft always Problematic. :D

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems but always with non english websites. The trick was to encode the output filename in ISO8859-1

This code (C#)  solved the issue.

response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + new String( fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO8859-1" ) );

Comment: but I need to use russian characters

Comment: Ok try to use the ISO8859-5, we foregners (non english speaking majority of the world ;) )  are the only ones getting in trouble like this.

Comment: Could you write how to set charset of filename?

Comment: How does the browser knew in which charset encoded filename? Maybe it is necessary somehow explicitly encoding the file name?